# Scala add to empty map

Tags: scala

I have a mutable Map in a List like so:

```
val aListMap = List(Map[StringType, Any])
```

I want to add key-val pairs to the map like:

```
aListMap(0) += ("aKey", "anElem")
```

I'm getting `Type mismatch: expected String, actual: (String, String)`. Is there a different syntax to do this?

Comment: Do you realize that you have a list of maps there? Is this what you intend?

Comment: You should be able to do `aListMap(0)("aKey") = "anElem"`.

Comment: I want a List where the first element is a Map. Is that the same?

Comment: well, **every** element is a Map, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to add parentheses at the end of the Map declaration (not familiar enough with Scala yet to know what this accomplishes):

```
val aListMap = List(Map[StringType, Any]())
```

I was then able to add like:

```
aListMap(0) += ("aKey" -> "anElem")
```

Comment: I also notice that your last line here has `->` instead of `,`.

Comment: `Map[StringType, Any]` is technically just a type, not an empty map. As you found, you can create an empty map with `Map[StringType, Any]()`. You can also use `Map.empty[StringType, Any]`, which might be a bit more readable

Comment: I'm confuded, `"aKey"` is not of type `StringType` but `String`

Comment: @KevinHoerr Yesandno. In other contexts, it could theoretically also be an expression `Map.apply[StringType,Any](implicitArgument)`. This is used pervasively in several libraries to summon typeclasses out of implicit scope. The syntactical similarity between the expression itself and its type is intentional.